# I've tried to retrieve the all the product and their total sales in the result

Tags: sql

I have the `Product` table with the product name and ID then also have the `receipt_product` table with product ID and receipt ID.

And finally, have the `receipt` table with the amount and the receipt ID. So I've tried to retrieve all the products and their total sales in the result.

This is my query and I know that my query is wrong and need to do something to make it correct.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1o3b.png)

```
select 
    p.name, sum(total) as total sales 
from 
    receipt_product rp 
right join 
    product p on p.product_id = rp.product_id 
inner join 
    receipt r on rp.receipt_id = r.receipt_id 
group by 
    p.name 
having 
    total_sales < 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the price of individual product and the quantity sold . So why are you taking the **receipt** table in consideration.

Try something like this.

```
select sum(p.price * r.quantity_sold) as "Total Sales",p.name 
from product p join receipt_product r
on p.product_id = r.product_id 
group by p.name;
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes its correct . that's my bad that I miss out on the price column in the product and trying to get the total sale for receipt table.

Am I trouble you to ask one more thing ? Im also try to retrieve the sales of categories for each quarter. But I really can't relate in query to find the sale of the categories since the receipt_product table has a relationship with product only  and also don't know how to query the condition to find the quarter of each year.

If is there any website or course that I can improve my logic and query skill , please share with me. 

Thank you sm !